# Please create a tag for powerbi

Tags: discussion

Power BI is a relatively new Data Visualisation tool from Microsoft - ref:

www.powerbi.com

I know there is already a powerbi tag on SO, but I think that site attracts a different audience to SU, and the powerbi questions on SU tend to be more from a programmers perspective.

I've already answered one Power BI question on SU, so you could say that is currently mis-tagged.

[Dynamically choose a chart measure in Power BI](https://superuser.com/q/1053362/310267)

Answer (score 2):

I've created [microsoft-powerbi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerbi).

Now we need some knowledgeable people to give the tag some content.

Comment: I don't have enough Priv, but this would be my effort: Power BI is a self service data integration and visualisation service provided by Microsoft, available at www.powerbi.com. It can integrate data from Excel and other Office programs, and all major databases and analytics tools and web services.

Comment: Power Bi is a cloud-based business data integration and visualisation service that gives you a single view of your data. Dashboards, reports and datasets are at the heart of Power BI. 

Power BI is split up into Power BI Desktop and the Power BI Service. Power BI Desktop focusses on data connections to datasets and visualizing them in dashboards and reports, then the Power BI Service provides data refresh and publishing content to users.

Comment: Power BI Desktop is built on a platform of Power Query (data integration Excel Add-In), Power Pivot (data analysis Excel Add-In) and Power View (data visualisation Excel Add-In).  Techniques from those tools are often applicable to Power BI Desktop.

Comment: @MikeHoney: Web based tools are off-topic.  Can you clarify what usage would be on-topic on SU?

Comment: @fixer1234 - Power BI Desktop is a windows desktop application you download and install.  It can be used on it's own or with the PBI web service. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/